# If G is a group such that $(a.b)^{2}=a^{2}.b^{2}$ for all a and b,Then show that G is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning

This is problem from I.N Herstein Page 35 Q3 .How should i start doing this ?Hints ? Thanks

Comment: Hint: Consider the left inverse of $a$ and the right inverse of $b$

Comment: You have given $abab=aabb$. Try applying some inverses.

Comment: @HowDoIMath abab=aabb ,now post multiplying by $b^{-1}$ , i get $aba=aabbb^{-1} $,so it becomes $aba=aab $,now pre multipl by $a^{-1}$ , i get$ ba=ab $...is that right ?

Comment: I assume that the question said that in G $(ab)^2 = a^2b^2$ for all $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In groups, you can "cancel", as long as you do it *from the same side*.

Explicitly:

$ac = bc \implies a = b$, and $ab = ac \implies b = c$

Proof:

$ac = bc \implies (ac)c^{-1} = (bc)c^{-1} \implies a(cc^{-1})= b(cc^{-1}) \implies ae = be \implies a = b$

$ac = bc \implies a^{-1}(ac) = a^{-1}(bc) \implies (a^{-1}a)b = (a^{-1}a)c \implies eb = ec \implies b = c$.

Now you are given that $(ab)^2 = a^2b^2$, that is:

$a(ab)b = a(ab)b$. Use the above.

Comment: i did as abab=aabb ,now post multiplying by $b^{-1}$ , i get $aba=aabbb^{-1} $,so it becomes $aba=aab $,now pre multipl by $a^{-1}$ , i get$ ba=ab $...is that right ?

Comment: That's exactly it.

Comment: But how is it valid that in my first step after post multiplying by b inverse i bracketed $bb^{-1}$ togethor .This is not associativity

Comment: $bb^{-1} = e$, so you can just omit any such pair in a string product of elements: $aabbb^{-1} = aabe = aab$.

Comment: This is valid in multiplication only .Isn't it ? We cannot say anything about other binary operations .Is that right ?

Comment: It's valid for any GROUP operation. Not all binary operations turn a set into a group. Note the NOTATION for abelian groups MAY be written differently, using $0$ instead of $e$, and denoting $ab$ as $a+b$, and $a^{-1}$ as $-a$, and $a^k$ as $ka$. Group operations are often "called" multiplication, but this is just nomenclature-sometimes group operations are "other things" (like composition of functions).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is the dot operations and if it's the same as group binary operation, but I will assume that it is, anyway it's group so there could be only one operation.
$$
(a \cdot b)^2 = a^2 \cdot b^2
$$

$$
(a \cdot b) (a \cdot b)  = a^2 \cdot b^2
$$
$$
a \cdot b \cdot a \cdot b = a \cdot a \cdot b \cdot b
$$

First multiply this element by $b^{-1}$ from right and then with $a^{-1}$ from left.

$$
b \cdot a = a \cdot b
$$

So it's abeliean group, if my assumtions were good.

Answer (score -1):

$(ab)^2=abab=a^2b^2 \rightarrow ab=ba $